# Pass Parameter on Axios Update Request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to pass a MongoDB's ObjectId (_id) as a parameter when making an Axios update request. I have a multi-step form that I am working with; after the first step the users account is created and they are logged in. The update request is made on step 2 of the form, so at this point the user is already authenticated.

My update request is below:

```
 const changeOnClick = e => {
        const users = {
            shareEmail, 
            filmmakerQuestion, 
            genres, 
            favoriteFilm, 
            imbd, 
            portfolio, 
            aboutYou
        }; 

        console.log(users)

        axios
            .put(`http://localhost:5000/users/update/:id`, users)
            .then(res => console.log(res.body))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err); 
            });
```

NodeJs Route:

```
router.put('/update/:id', (req, res) => {
    Users.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(user => {
            user.shareEmail = req.body.shareEmail; 
            user.filmmakerQuestion = req.body.filmmakerQuestion; 
            user.genres = req.body.genres; 
            user.favoriteFilms = req.body.favoriteFilms; 
            user.imbd = req.body.portfolio; 
            user.portfolio = req.body.portfolio; 
            user.aboutYou = req.body.aboutYou
          

        user 
            .save()
            .then(() => res.json("The User is UPDATED succesfully!"))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json(`Error: ${err}`)); 
        }) 
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json(`Error: ${err}`));  
});
```

Form code (step 1):

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'; 
import Exit from '../cancel.svg'; 
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
// import Register from './Components/register';
import axios from "axios"; 
// import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import UserContext from "../context/UserContext"; 


Modal.setAppElement('#root'); 

const Profile = () => {


    const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState (true);
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm ();
    const [shareEmail, setshareEmail] = useState(); 
    const [filmmakerQuestion, setfilmmakerQuestion] = useState(); 
    const [genres, setgenres] = useState(); 
    const [favoriteFilm, setfavoriteFilm] = useState(); 
    const [imbd, setimbd] = useState(); 
    const [portfolio, setportfolio] = useState(); 
    const [aboutYou, setaboutYou] = useState(); 
    const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
    
    const { userData } = useContext(UserContext); 
    const history = useHistory();


    const changeOnClick = e => {
        const users = {
            shareEmail, 
            filmmakerQuestion, 
            genres, 
            favoriteFilm, 
            imbd, 
            portfolio, 
            aboutYou
        }; 

        console.log(users)

        axios
            .put(`http://localhost:5000/users/${userData.user.id}`, users)
            .then(res => console.log(res.body))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err); 
            }); 

            history.push("/Landing/ProfilePic")
    }; 

    return(
        <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={() => setModalIsOpen(false)} className='createBorder'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(changeOnClick)} encType="multipart/form-data" >
            <div className='border-bottom'>
                    <img onClick= {() => setModalIsOpen(false)} src={Exit} className='exitButton-two' alt='X' />
                    <span className='complete-profile'>Complete your profile</span> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>Please mark if your email can be shared with filmmakers:</p>
                    <div className='shareblock'>
                        <input onChange={e => setshareEmail(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} className='sharePosition' type="radio" htmlFor='shareEmail' value='yes' name="shareEmail"/> 
                            <label htmlFor='shareEmail'>Yes, share my email with filmmakers</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className='shareblock'>
                        <input onChange={e => setshareEmail(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} className='sharePosition' type="radio" htmlFor='noShare' value='no' name="shareEmail"/>
                            <label htmlFor='noShare'>No, do not share my email</label>
                    </div>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>Are you a filmmaker?</p>
                    <div className='shareblock'>
                        <input onChange={e => setfilmmakerQuestion(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} className='sharePosition' type="radio" htmlFor='yesFilmmaker' value='yes' name="filmmakerQuestion" />
                            <label htmlFor='yesFilmmaker'>Yes, I am a filmmaker</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className='shareblock'>
                        <input onChange={e => setfilmmakerQuestion(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} className='sharePosition' type="radio" htmlFor='noFilmmaker' value='no' name="filmmakerQuestion" />
                            <label htmlFor='noFilmmaker'>No, I am not a filmmaker</label>
                    </div>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>What genres of film do you like? Check all that apply:</p>
                    <div>
                        <div className='shareBox'>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='horror' type="checkbox" htmlFor='horror' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='horror' className='move'>Horror</label>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='animation' type="checkbox" htmlFor='animation' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='animation'>Animation</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className='shareBox'> 
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='drama' type="checkbox" name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='drama' className='move'>Drama</label>  
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='comedy' type="checkbox" htmlFor='comedy' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='comedy' className='move'>Comedy</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div className='shareBox'>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='action' type="checkbox" htmlFor='action' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='action' className='move'>Action</label>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='documentary' type="checkbox" htmlFor='documentary' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='documentary'>Documentary</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className='shareBox'>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='scifi' type="checkbox" htmlFor='scifi' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='scifi' className='movemore'>Sci-Fi</label>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='expriemental' type="checkbox" name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='experimental'>Experimental</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>What are your favorite films?</p>
                    <input ref={register({required: false})} onChange={e => setfavoriteFilm(e.target.value)} className='inputsThree' name='favoriteFilm' autoComplete='off'></input>
                    <p className='minifieldsNew'>These will be shared to your profile.</p>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>Please share a link to your IMBD profile if available:</p>
                    <input ref={register({required: false})} onChange={e => setimbd(e.target.value)} className='inputsThree' name='imbd' autoComplete='off'></input>
                    <p className='minifieldsNew'>If you are a filmmaker, our community is very interested to learn more about what projects you have been a part of. This will be shared on your profile</p>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>If you have a link to a portfolio please share below:</p>
                    <input ref={register({required: false})} onChange={e => setportfolio(e.target.value)} className='inputsThree' name='portfolio' autoComplete='off'></input>
                    <p className='minifieldsNew'>This is your chance to show your work. This will be shared on your profile</p>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>Anything else you want to share about yourself?</p>
                    <input ref={register({required: false})} onChange={e => setaboutYou(e.target.value)} className='inputsThree' name='aboutYou' autoComplete='off'></input>
                    <p className='minifieldsNewNew'>Our community is very interested in learning more about you as a filmmaker</p>  
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type='submit' className='signupButton3'>Sign Up</button>

                {/* <a onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} type='submit' className='doneButtontwo'>
                    <span>Done</span>
                </a> */}
                <div>
                    <a href='/GetStarted' className='later'>I'll do this later</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        </Modal>
    )
}

export default Profile;
```

Form code (step 2):

```
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(changeOnClick)} encType="multipart/form-data" >
            <div className='border-bottom'>
                    <img onClick= {() => setModalIsOpen(false)} src={Exit} className='exitButton-two' alt='X' />
                    <span className='complete-profile'>Complete your profile</span> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>Please mark if your email can be shared with filmmakers:</p>
                    <div className='shareblock'>
                        <input onChange={e => setshareEmail(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} className='sharePosition' type="radio" htmlFor='shareEmail' value='yes' name="shareEmail"/> 
                            <label htmlFor='shareEmail'>Yes, share my email with filmmakers</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className='shareblock'>
                        <input onChange={e => setshareEmail(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} className='sharePosition' type="radio" htmlFor='noShare' value='no' name="shareEmail"/>
                            <label htmlFor='noShare'>No, do not share my email</label>
                    </div>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>Are you a filmmaker?</p>
                    <div className='shareblock'>
                        <input onChange={e => setfilmmakerQuestion(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} className='sharePosition' type="radio" htmlFor='yesFilmmaker' value='yes' name="filmmakerQuestion" />
                            <label htmlFor='yesFilmmaker'>Yes, I am a filmmaker</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className='shareblock'>
                        <input onChange={e => setfilmmakerQuestion(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} className='sharePosition' type="radio" htmlFor='noFilmmaker' value='no' name="filmmakerQuestion" />
                            <label htmlFor='noFilmmaker'>No, I am not a filmmaker</label>
                    </div>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>What genres of film do you like? Check all that apply:</p>
                    <div>
                        <div className='shareBox'>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='horror' type="checkbox" htmlFor='horror' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='horror' className='move'>Horror</label>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='animation' type="checkbox" htmlFor='animation' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='animation'>Animation</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className='shareBox'> 
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='drama' type="checkbox" name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='drama' className='move'>Drama</label>  
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='comedy' type="checkbox" htmlFor='comedy' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='comedy' className='move'>Comedy</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div className='shareBox'>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='action' type="checkbox" htmlFor='action' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='action' className='move'>Action</label>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='documentary' type="checkbox" htmlFor='documentary' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='documentary'>Documentary</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className='shareBox'>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='scifi' type="checkbox" htmlFor='scifi' name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='scifi' className='movemore'>Sci-Fi</label>
                            <input onChange={e => setgenres(e.target.value)} ref={register({required: false})} value='expriemental' type="checkbox" name="genres" />
                                <label htmlFor='experimental'>Experimental</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>What are your favorite films?</p>
                    <input ref={register({required: false})} onChange={e => setfavoriteFilm(e.target.value)} className='inputsThree' name='favoriteFilm' autoComplete='off'></input>
                    <p className='minifieldsNew'>These will be shared to your profile.</p>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>Please share a link to your IMBD profile if available:</p>
                    <input ref={register({required: false})} onChange={e => setimbd(e.target.value)} className='inputsThree' name='imbd' autoComplete='off'></input>
                    <p className='minifieldsNew'>If you are a filmmaker, our community is very interested to learn more about what projects you have been a part of. This will be shared on your profile</p>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>If you have a link to a portfolio please share below:</p>
                    <input ref={register({required: false})} onChange={e => setportfolio(e.target.value)} className='inputsThree' name='portfolio' autoComplete='off'></input>
                    <p className='minifieldsNew'>This is your chance to show your work. This will be shared on your profile</p>
                <p className='filmmakerQ'>Anything else you want to share about yourself?</p>
                    <input ref={register({required: false})} onChange={e => setaboutYou(e.target.value)} className='inputsThree' name='aboutYou' autoComplete='off'></input>
                    <p className='minifieldsNewNew'>Our community is very interested in learning more about you as a filmmaker</p>  
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type='submit' className='signupButton3'>Sign Up</button>

                {/* <a onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} type='submit' className='doneButtontwo'>
                    <span>Done</span>
                </a> */}
                <div>
                    <a href='/GetStarted' className='later'>I'll do this later</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Use insomnia I see that the update endpoints work; additionally I see that if I manually take a userId and use it instead of the ":id" in the axios request, then the PUT request will update successfully.

If I send the form data right now on my local environment the network response is:

```
"Error: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \":id\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Users\""
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226634/discussion-on-question-by-ethan-pass-parameter-on-axios-update-request).